# Ext JS 5 - passing parameters between windows

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to Ext JS 5. What I would like to do : set the value of a field on panel from a row selected on a grid on a "pop-up" window. The field whose value I will set is contained on a panel from which the popup is opened. I do not know if this is a case of "parent-child" window (bec I have seen some questions here that describe such a situation) but these are the details of my code:

- I have 2 views that have their separate controllers.
- The panel that contains the field i need to set has a button. When the button is clicked it create and shows a window that contains a grid of values.
- Once a row on said grid is double clicked, it gets a value there and needs to pass that value back to the calling panel and sets said value as the value of the field. Thereafter the window closes.

From the controller of the main window (w/c contains the field) here is the code that creates the window:

```
 onClickSearchLookup: function (b) {
    var w = Ext.create('Entitlement.view.group2org.OrgLookup', { });
    w.show();
},
```

On the double click event of the OrgLookup view's grid here is the code:

```
onRowDblClick: function(grid, record){
    alert(record.data.name);                
    var v = this.getView();
    v.close();
}
```

I know this works I am able to get the values of the row selected on the grid and the window closes properly, but how do I get a reference to the field on the previous panel to set its value before I close this window?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Look at the section called 'Using Refs'
the ref: is what ever you want to name it
the selector: can be the alias or xtype of your view

Once you have a reference to your view, you should be able to go down to your field by use way of it's itemId or xtype.

I think that should give you the reference you need to set the value.